# How can I use multiple with statements and then use the variables in the SELECT query afterwards?

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute 3 `WITH` SQL queries, and then use them in the final `SELECT` query in the end, but I run into an error after the first WITH statement:

```
WITH display_name_fid AS 
(
    SELECT fid 
    FROM field 
    WHERE name = 'DisplayName' AND sid = 8
),
index_clid AS 
(
    SELECT clid 
    FROM class 
    WHERE name = 'Index'
),
ids AS 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM SVAL 
    WHERE fid = display_name_fid AND val IN ('bchm30p')
)
SELECT ident 
FROM id 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ids)
  AND clid = index_clid;
```

When I execute the above, in the second `WITH` statement, the `WITH` itself is highlighted and SQL complains

> SQL Error [42703]: column "display_name_fid" does not exist.   Position: 203

Is my syntax incorrect?

Ideally, the output is just a single value.

Comment: Thank Jaytiger, that works, but I'm still getting a small issue-

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  (I guess PostgreSQL ?)

Comment: Yes, Dbeaver PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am getting the same error in DBeaver as in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/RjGDkGYM), which is "ERROR:  relation "field" does not exist"

Comment: This is incorrect: `WHERE fid=display_name_fid` , because `display_name_fid` is a table name, not a fieldname!

Comment: `field` is a table.

Comment: @Luuk `field` is the table. `display_name_fid` is what the first `WITH` statement is trying to obtain from the database, it is supposed to be a value.

Comment: Change the where-clause to: `WHERE fid=display_name_fid.fid`   (Because `display_name_fid` is still a table... )

Comment: `SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "display_name_fid"¶  Position: 203` I get this when I change it to `WHERE fid=display_name_fid.fid`

Comment: Yes, with the last change you are selecting from the **table** `display_name_fid`, and that **table** is (as the error says...) not in the FROM-clause.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first WITH is required Try this :

```
WITH display_name_fid AS (
    SELECT fid from field where name='DisplayName' AND sid=8
),
index_clid AS (
    SELECT clid from class WHERE name = 'Index'
),
ids AS (
    SELECT id 
    from SVAL s
    inner join display_name_fid d on d.fid = s.fid
    WHERE val IN ('bchm30p')
)
SELECT ident 
from id
inner join index_clid i on i.clid = id.clid
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ids);
```

Comment: OK, it works, but I get the error `SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "display_name_fid" does not exist¶  Position: 205`. Am I allowed to use `display_name_fid`like I have above?

Comment: do you have any table called *id* ?

Comment: Sorry it works, I just had to get rid of the missing empty line. But I still get the above error in my comment.

Comment: Yes I do have a table called `id`.

Comment: You cant access *display_name_fid* this way, you need to use an inner join for exemple, check my update

Comment: Ohh is what follows `WITH` supposed to be a table??? I thought it was a variable that I am filling in... So my intention is for `display_name_fid` to be a variable that holds a single number- which is produced by the `AS` statement.

Comment: Its a temporary result set kind of temporary table

Comment: OK thanks, the above returns an error `SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "index_clid" does not exist`

Comment: `index_clid` is defined in the second `WITH` statement.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you have to use a join clause to match your data with the CTEs, check my update

Comment: The query runs now but it doesn't return anything... I think the logic has been modified.

Comment: Maybe its an idea to open a new question with some simple data and the expected output, and the query that you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your help SelVazi. Instead of the WITH statement, is there a way to declare a variable and assign it to the output of a query? Something like:

`variable = "SELECT * FROM sval WHERE field_id=5"` ?